# NginX GZIP PHP Files

Tags: php, nginx, gzip

Can I gzip PHP files safely?
I'm using these settings:

```
add_header Pragma public;
add_header Cache-Control "public";
expires 1d;
```

Like I'm testing it now and it works great, but is there a security risk doing this? Would the php files be stored in text on the users computer?

Comment: Those settings have nothing to do with gzip.

Comment: I have text/php in gzip_types im just setting the expire date with the above commands to finalize it.

Comment: Setting the expire date has nothing to do with gzip. Really. They're often mentioned in conjunction with one another, but they're two totally different things.

Comment: How can I get php to do something with gzip then because setting an expire date is service it from cache making it super fast.